# Change Div style onclick

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have 2 tabs at the top of a page. When one tab is clicked, I would like that tab to have an "active" class and the other tab to have an "inactive" class so that the user can see what tab is currently selected. How can I go about doing this with javascript/css?

```
<div class="tabActive">
Option 1
</div>

<div id="tabInactive">
Option 2
</div>
```

Comment: Do you use a library like jQuery?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not for this project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another non-jQuery solution could be the following that works with more than two `div`:

```
function changeClass(elClass) {
  var divsLenght = document.getElementsByTagName("div").length;
  for (var i = 0; i < divsLenght; i++) { 
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].className = "tabInactive"; 
  } 
  elClass.className = "tabActive";   
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/opetec/2

Comment: How do I prevent this from changing all the other divs on the page?

Comment: @Mike add one more `class` in each `div`, for example menu, and get the lenght of them. demo: http://jsbin.com/opetec/4

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="tabInactive" onclick="this.classname='tabActive'"></div>
```

if using jquery:

```
$("div.tabInactive").click(function() {
    $("div.tabInactive").removeClass("tabActive");
    $(this).addClass("tabActive");
});
```

Comment: I guess the other tab should have its active class removed again as well (in your non-jQuery example).

Comment: +1 for including a non-jquery answer, but the JS should be [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

Give your tabs a class of "tab"...
HTML:

```
<div class="tab">
...
</div>
<div class="tab">
...
</div>
```

JS:

```
function getByClass(_class, elem) {
    var i, result = [], elems = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); //get the elements
   for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].className.indexOf(_class) !== -1) { //if the elements have the class passed in, add it to the result array
            result.push(elems[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
var i, tabs = getByClass("tab", "div"); //get all divs with class tab
for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) { //for each tab...
    tabs[i].onclick = function() { //wire up it's click event...
        //to clear the other tabs...
        var j;
        for(j=0; j < tabs.length; j++) {
           tabs[j].className = tabs[j].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
       this.className += " active"; //where active is a class predefined in the CSS 
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/pqMq2/12/

Answer (score 1):

here's a solution that doesn't use any jQuery!  it does assume there is only 2 tabs thought.

http://jsfiddle.net/nYpV3/

```
<div id="tab1" onclick="setToActive(this, 'tab2');">
Option 1
</div>

<div id="tab2" onclick="setToActive(this, 'tab1');">
Option 2
</div>

function setToActive(me, otherId){

    me.className='active';
    document.getElementById(otherId).className='inactive';
}
```

Comment: This is a good example but will only work on two tabs. If there were other tabs added for what ever reason it wouldn't work as well anymore.

Comment: Probably can be recreated using the `:target` CSS selector - the only kink there would be to figure out the initial state.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jQuery

```
<div class="tab active">
Option 1
</div>

<div class="tab">
Option 2
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    $(".tab").live("click", function(){
        $(".tab").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my guess:

```
$('.tabActive, #tabInactive').click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('active');
}
```