# Change div class onclick --- and *save* the change

Tags: javascript, css, dom

There are many questions that ask how to change the class of a div in a JavaScript click handler, e.g., here: [Change Div style onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655423/change-div-style-onclick).  I understand that well (just change .className), and it works.

However, when I follow a link from my page to somewhere else, and then click the back button, the class names are reverted.  (Safari and Firefox get it right, Chrome does not.)  In Chrome, most other changes I make dynamically, e.g., to click handlers, are also reverted when I go back to the page (although it remembers freshly inserted new divs).

Note that neither Chrome nor the other browsers are reloading the page when I press "back"; they must just take it from the cache.  (I update the state on the server using ajax, so it works fine when the browsers reload the page.)

I am not really a web developer, so this is a bit puzzling.  What is the standard practice here?  Should I use history.replaceState() every time I change the divs?  Should I save the changes in a state variable and reload them every time there is a popstate event?  Instead of changing div classnames, should I delete the div and insert a fresh one (with all the old div's children)?

I am using vanilla JavaScript here (no jquery even) and would prefer to keep it that way if possible.

Comment: A testcase would be helpful. If a browser loads the page from the HTTP cache, it shouldn't "remember freshly inserted new div". If it loads the page from the other cache ("bfcache") in mozilla, it restores the DOM as it was, including 'class' changes. It could be that the page's JS code doesn't work correctly when going back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but you will need additional ways to remember it

You could try one of these:

**Cookies:** This definitely looks like the best way to go

**Pass Vars on the URL**: example: www.mywebsite.com?myvar=red. This would be easier using PHP, but still is possible in pure JS (but I don't recommend it)

**Store it on Database:** (don't recommend this at all)

**Store it in input elements:** In current browsers, input element values (of radio buttons, hidden, etc.), persist after POST-ing, and returning using the back button.

These are just some options, but I don't recommend using them for what you want (it is a waste of time and effort if you weight the Pros and Cons of what you want to do)

Comment: localStorage is another option.

Comment: Just to confirm: If I use localStorage or cookies, then I should add a popstate event handler to update the page data when the user hits back?  Is there any way of just telling the browser that it needs to update its cache?

Answer (score 0):

You can save state in cookies and restore it when page loaded.
Also you can save it on server-side (send state using ajax, when it changed). And send prepared document to client when it requested again.
Browser forget all states when you reload page.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  Sorry, I was unclear.  The page is not being reloaded by Chrome or the other browsers when I press the back button, I suppose since it is cached.  I do use ajax to save the state server-side so it renders properly on a reload.