# change input button style using javascript on click

Tags: php, javascript, css, codeigniter

I wanted to change the style of the button I'm using every time I clicked that button and together change it's text. Problem is I wanted to do it using and external javascript which I'm not that familiar with it's syntax. To elaborate what I wanted to do is to have a button having a text displaying like: Very Good, Good, Moderate, Failed. Each of the text has it's own assigned gradient color using CSS let's say a gradient of Green for Very Good, Yellow for Good, Orange for Moderate and Red for failed. Tried searching for it but I only landed on an irrelevant posts. What I think is that I need to make a button with on click and everytime I click the javascript will add int values from 0 and reset back to 0 after it reaches 3. then I think I can use case for the css class assigning like `this.style="failed"` Well I don't know if this is possible.

UPDATE:
After doing some research I've managed to do something about the changing texts (using javascript alone) but not yet the class part since I think the class is a keyword in javascript. here's my script so far:

```
    function buttonChange(){
    var button = document.getElementById("stats");
    switch (button.value)
    {
      case "Very Good":
      button.value="Good";
      break;
      case "Good":
      button.value="Moderate";
      break;
      case "Moderate":
      button.value="Failed";
      break;
      default:
      button.value="Very Good";
    }       
}
```

now the problem is the style. :)

Comment: post some codes. Its'll be easier to solve the problem

Comment: This might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655423/change-div-style-onclick

Comment: u r creating different text everytime or just toggling between two , three texts ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery your code could look something like this:

```
var values = new Array('Very Good', 'Good', 'Moderate', 'Failed');
var colors = new Array('lime', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red');

$('#rate').click(function() {

    // current index is stored in data attribute
    var idx = $(this).data('value') + 1;

    // last value was selected -> go back to first one
    if (idx >= values.length) {
        idx = 0;
    }

    // update data attribute with current index
    $(this).data('value', idx);

    // update button text
    $(this).val(values[idx]);

    // update button background color
    $(this).css('background-color', colors[idx]);

});​
```

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gQZVw/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery solution to cycle through the button text and the background colour for the four states:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var states = ['Very Good', 'Good', 'Moderate', 'Failed'];
    var colors = ['green', 'Yellow', 'orange', 'red'];
    var index = 0;
    $('body').on('click', '#button', function(){
        index = ++index%4;
        $("#button").html(states[index]);
        $("#button").css('background-color',colors[index]);
    });
});
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <button id="button" style="background-color:green"; type="button">Very Good</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note the **modulus** (%) operator which simplifies the circular increment of 'index' from 0 to 3.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this:
[Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

I think that your CSS should have all the styles for gradients and stuff like this:

```
.VeryGood {//gradient for very good
}
.Good {//gradient for good
}
.Moderate {//gradient for moderate
}
.Failed { //gradient for failed
}
```

and then, use this javascript and html :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 1; //change to 0 if element dosen't need to have any class by default
var classArray = new Array();
classArray[0] = 'VeryGood';
classArray[1] = 'Good';
classArray[2] = 'Moderate';
classArray[3] = 'Failed';
    function changeClass()
    {
        document.getElementById("MyElement").className = classArray[i];        
        i++;
        if(i>=3){
            i=0;
        }
    }
</script>
...
<button onclick="changeClass()">My Button</button>
```

now, the array key `i` increases every time the button is clicked, so by default, you can have your element's class as VeryGood, and every time the button is clicked, it advances to next class, so after VeryGood comes Good then Moderate then Failed, ithe it resets itself to VeryGood. hope this is what you are looking for :)